# should "netxxx" be included before or after "netcoreappxxx" in project.json

Tags: .net, .net-core

My tests don't run if I have netcoreapp listed first but if I have net462 listed first I get an incorrect result from Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(). 
What is the recommended format or should I just go with what breaks the least number of things.

"netcoreapp1.1" is listed first in project.json:
Assembly: System.IO.FileSystem, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(): C:\Temp\ProjectManager\ProjectManager\ProjectManager\src\ProjectManager.Tests

'test-nunit' returned '-2147450749'.
No tests will run.

=================================
"net462" is listed first in project.json:
Assembly mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(): C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE
Tests will run

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "dependencies": {
    "ProjectManager.Core": "1.0.0-*",
    "ProjectManager.Domain": "1.0.0-*",
    "ProjectManager.Gateway": "1.0.0-*",
    "ProjectManager.Model": "1.0.0-*",
    "ProjectManager.Services": "1.0.0-*",
    "ProjectManager.Services.REST": "1.0.0-*",
    "ProjectManager.Services.WCF": "1.0.0-*",
    "NUnit": "3.5.0",
    "dotnet-test-nunit": "3.4.0-beta-3",
    "Moq": "4.6.38-alpha",
    "Autofac": "4.2.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions": "1.1.0",
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.1"
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "win10-x64": {}
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "imports": [
        "netcoreapp1.1",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ],
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.1.0",
        "System.ServiceModel.Duplex": "4.3.0",
        "System.ServiceModel.Http": "4.3.0",
        "System.ServiceModel.NetTcp": "4.3.0",
        "System.ServiceModel.Security": "4.3.0",
        "System.Xml.XmlSerializer": "4.3.0"
      }
    },
    "net462": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.Runtime.Serialization": "4.0.0.0",
        "System.ServiceModel": "4.0.0.0",
        "System.Xml": "4.0.0.0"
      },
      "dependencies": {}
    }
  },
  "testRunner": "nunit"
}
```

code:

```
    [Test]
    public void CurrentDirTest()
    {
        string dir = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    }
```

Comment: Could you show the project.json and the code that causes the issues?

Comment: @svick edited per request.